# How do i update contents of a div when there are many of the same class?

Tags: jquery

i want to have a section of divs that are each updateable with buttons. i have the buttons working and the info sent to the database with a .post in jquery. to send the value of the item i want to update i use 'this' so this not a problem. but since i have individual divs of the same class, how would the .done function know which of these to update? i am still learning how to do this sort of thing. Thanks in advance!

```
$(".confirm-request-show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("confirmrequest.php",
    {
        requestID: $(this).val(),
        action: 'confirm'
    })
    .done(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $('#confirm-request-div-' + id).empty().load('confirmrequestdiv.php?requestID=' + id );
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    })
});
```

Update: got it working, all i had to do was declare id BEFORE the done() function. not sure why, maybe someone can explain this nuance to me?

```
$(".confirm-request-show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.post("confirmrequest.php",
    {
        requestID: id,
        action: 'confirm'
    })
    .done(function() {          
        $('#confirm-request-div-' + id).empty().load('confirmrequestdiv.php?requestID=' + id );
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    })
});
```

Comment: Post the HTML and a jsFiddle.net example.

Comment: you can use an id on each of them to locate an specific one when neccesary, another option is to obtain the array of div's and iterate over them to find the rigth one. But i prefer the 1st method is more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `.confirm-request-show` button is nested inside `.confirmrequestdiv` you could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="confirmrequestdiv">
    <input type="submit" class="confirm-request-show" value="1" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(this).closest('.confirmrequestdiv').empty().load( "confirmrequestdiv.php?showID=" + $(this).val() );
```

This is using the button that has been clicked as a starting point and is looking for an ancestor that has the `.confirmrequestdiv` class.

If your button is not nested inside the div, you could find a common ancestor like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="commonancestor">
    <div class="confirmrequestdiv">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="confirm-request-show" value="1" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(this).closest('.commonancestor').find('.confirmrequestdiv').empty().load( "confirmrequestdiv.php?showID=" + $(this).val() );
```

If the elements don't have a convenient common ancestor (or if all the `confirmrequestdiv` classes are in a common container you can take the `id` approach:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="confirmrequestdiv" id="confirmrequestdiv-1"></div>
    <div class="confirmrequestdiv" id="confirmrequestdiv-2"></div>
    <div class="confirmrequestdiv" id="confirmrequestdiv-3"></div>
    <div class="confirmrequestdiv" id="confirmrequestdiv-4"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" class="confirm-request-show" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" class="confirm-request-show" value="2" />
    <input type="submit" class="confirm-request-show" value="3" />
    <input type="submit" class="confirm-request-show" value="4" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
var id = $(this).val();
('#confirmrequestdiv-' + id).empty().load("confirmrequestdiv.php?showID=" + id);
```

But to really help you, we would need to see the HTML structure.

Comment: one other quick question - for some reason the button is not being disabled. is it not ok to use this to set the attribute to disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is where you want to use an ID. Simply give the div you want to update a unique ID, and then use `$('#whateverIDyouGaveTheDiv')` in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to approach this problem, I just created a unique ID associated with each div element. For example, id="element1" then I would pass the digit part of the ID to javascript, like so onclick="function(1)". But this requires the use of onclick event inside the div element.

Then inside your jquery you can associate the two together $('#element' + id)...... etc.